# use Template Toolkit for plain .html files?

Tags: html, perl, templates

Right now I have a site that uses Perl and Template Toolkit (using the `Template` module) for pages that require calculation and/or database access but regular HTML files for the the rest of the pages.  However, I have discovered that it would be nice if I had access to templating goodness for even the "plain HTML" pages, if only for the convenience of "including" standard headers and footers, etc.

What is the easiest way to introduce this with the least amount of disruption to the current site?  (i.e. I would prefer not to have to change all the filenames and links).

Comment: Another idea (although not exactly my question)... if all that is required is including headers and footers, etc... just use mod_include in apache

Answer (score 5):

The two approaches that spring to my mind are:

1. Process the static files off-line using [ttree](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html)
2. Write some sort of mod_perl hander to run all .html files through TT before outputting

Comment: What would the handler look like?

Comment: It would look at a URI, map that onto a file, and run it through TT. Its been a *long* time since I've written any mod_perl though, so I can't be more specific then that without relearning a bunch of stuff that I don't have time to do right now.